# Shiny inputPanel does not change colour entirely

Tags: r, shiny

I'm developing an interactive app in Shiny. As part of the interface I would like to make the inputPanel colour a pleasant green colour. However when I use `style = background-color: #EFF8CD"`, only the inside of the inputPanel changes colour, leaving a grey border on the outside. Below is some code that reproduces the issue, using a different set of colours to show better contrast:

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

   # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(style = "background-color: #E1AAAA",
                   inputPanel(style = "background-color: #EFF811",
                      sliderInput("bins",
                      "Number of bins:",
                      min = 1,
                      max = 50,
                      value = 30)
                      )
      ),

      # Show a plot of the generated distribution
      mainPanel(
         plotOutput("distPlot")
      )
   )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

   output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
      # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
      x    <- faithful[, 2] 
      bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

      # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
      hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
   })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I include an image of the generated app showing the behaviour. Is there a way of changing all of the colour of the inputPanel, or is this just an idiosyncrasy of the package?
[Image of example app showing grey border around inputPanel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkyR3.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the grey border using the following `css`:

```
tags$head(tags$style(type = 'text/css',".shiny-input-panel{padding: 0px 0px !important;}"))
```

In your code it would be something like this:

```
# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),
  tags$head(tags$style(type = 'text/css',".shiny-input-panel{padding: 0px 0px !important;}")),
  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(style = "background-color: #E1AAAA",
                 inputPanel(style = "background-color: #EFF811",
                            sliderInput("bins",
                                        "Number of bins:",
                                        min = 1,
                                        max = 50,
                                        value = 30)
                 )
    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot")
    )
  )
)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: That's great, thanks. It's given me a leg up into editing the CSS. It's resolved with `tags$head(tags$style(type = 'text/css',".shiny-input-panel{background-color: darkgreen}"))`, which keeps the border but gives it the correct colour.